# integral boundaries

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If $C_1=\{(x,y,z) such\,\, that \,\,0<x=y=z<1\}$ and $C_2=\{(x,y,z) such\,\, that \,\, 0<x<y<z<1\}$ find the volume of each..For the second one the bounareis of the triple integral are $x=0$ to $y$  and $y$ from $0=z$ and $z=0$ to $1$ what about the boundaries of $C_1$?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should write your integral like this:
$$I_{C1} = \int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x, y, z)dx.dy.dz$$
And for C2:
$$I_{C2} = \int_y^1\int_x^z\int_0^yf(x, y, z)dx.dy.dz$$

Comment: I dont think so.. because this represent a straight line in 3D so the volume will be zero... I think it is different from $0<x,y,z<1$

Comment: I see what you mean. But I interpreted C1 and C2 as mere boundaries of a triple integral of a function that was not given to us.

Comment: Sorry, I probably misunderstood your question.